# Int32.Parse error FormatException

Tags: c#

I am getting this very weird error,

```
Int32.Parse("455.55"); // gives Format Exception Error


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9586043
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
```

Comment: "455.55" is not parsable as int32. What do you expect this to return? An integer equal to 455.55?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Silly mistake on the part of mine. :(

Answer (score 2):

455.55 is not an Int32 type, hence the exception. (Int32 ranges from about -2 billion to 2 billion, and are only integers, i.e. numbers with no fractional part.) If you want a decimal number, use double.Parse("455.55").

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned the value you're working with is not an integer but infact a floating point value. If you really want it to be an int you can do:

```
(int)double.Parse("455.55");
```

This will parse it to a double then cast it to an int causing the result to give you an int with the value of 455.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're trying to parse a variable that is not an integer

```
455.55
```

is NOT an integer, it's a `double`

```
455
```

is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to put a decimal (or double) into an integer. Try :

```
double.Parse("455.55");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a floating point with Int32. You have to use Double.parse instead.